# Output local variables in real-time as they're defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to automatically output variable names and values to Rails logs as they're defined?

For example:

```
company_count = Company.count
person_count = Person.count
```

Instead of doing something like `logger.debug` for each line, can we set up some method that automatically outputs something like the following as each line is processed?

```
company_count set to 12
person_count set to 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get such array using `local_variables` and `eval`

```
local_variables.map { |var| "#{var} set to #{eval(var.to_s)}" }
```

Keep attention, in the irb, pry or other interactive console `local_variables` could contain some "system" local variables and you need to filter this array (if you run separate `ruby file.rb` you don't need it). For example, `local_variables.grep_v(/_/)`

You can use this idea with logger. I don't sure you need to log local variables everywhere

You can call it as

```
local_variables.each { |var| Rails.logger.debug("#{var} set to #{eval(var.to_s)}") }
```

Comment: Part of my question is how to create that output *as* variables are defined, not just in one go.